# How work auto completion with apt

Tags: debian, apt, autocomplete

When you use TAB on `apt` shows some results: `autoclean, autoremove, changelog, depends, download, full-upgrade, install, moo, purge, remove, show, source, upgrade, autopurge...`. Those results are simply suggestions or are stored files (executables)? And if yes where are stored this apt files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The suggestions come from a specific completion script, `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/apt` (for bash). This “knows” what subcommands are available, and which options each one supports.

You’ll find many other completions in the same directory. See [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html) for a description of how completion works.